# Can we host a Self Contained ASP.NET Core App on Linux Server with Shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Now a days, I was reading about ASP.NET Core & I came to know that we can publish an ASP.NET Core app as a Self Contained app.

From Self Container App - I understand, when we publish the app, it will also copy the Run-time files for .NET Core environment in the published directory.

**My simple question is that -** if we copy the self-contained ASP.NET Core apps's published code to a web-directory of the Linux Server having shared hosting. Will that work?

Comment: Ask your hoster. Shared hosting typically means you *can't* just copy executables because the same server VM is used by multiple clients. Can you just copy the published packages to a Linux box and run it? Yes.

Comment: @Tseng - I dont want to invest 3 to 5 $ per month when I can get free shared hosting to test my apps.

Comment: @Panagiotis - I don't have experience of Linux hosting...But on godday windows hosting I get a wwwroot folder where we copy the published code...I was thinking to do similar with Linux. Does Self-contained published code contains executables ?

Comment: That's a question for the *hoster*. It depends on how restricted the environment is. Luckily, Scott Hansleman wrote [Running ASP.NET Core on GoDaddy's cheapest shared Linux Hosting - Don't Try This At Home](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RunningASPNETCoreOnGoDaddysCheapestSharedLinuxHostingDontTryThisAtHome.aspx) a few months back. At the time, the cheapest hosting option was a pretty locked down environment with missing libraries and no package managers